# Будильник под Android. Создание условия для отключения будильника

Tags: java, android, android-alarm-manager

Здравствуйте. 
Я новичок в программировании под Android. Для колледжа необходимо внести некоторые изменения в проект. 
В моей проекте, при срабатывании будильника, для его отключения, необходимо провести пальцем вниз. Необходимо изменить условия так, чтобы отключение будильника производилось после решения легкого математического примера(например 31+16=ввести ответ). 
На layoute, которое вызывается при срабатывании будильника, я создал EditText и Button, для ввода, но не знаю какой код прописать. Очень много вариантов пробовал, либо никакой реакции, либо много ошибок.
Вот что содержится  в java файле:

```js
package com.home.abel.wakemeup;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by abel on 3/2/16.
 */
public class AlarmManagement {

    public static final int WITH_DATABASE = 1;

    public static void enableAlarm(Context context, Alarm alarm, int flag) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("hh", alarm.getHh());
        bundle.putInt("mm", alarm.getMm());
        bundle.putInt("id", alarm.getId());
        bundle.putString("rpt", alarm.getRepeat());
        bundle.putString("text", alarm.getText());
        bundle.putString("state", alarm.getState());
        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                alarm.getHh() * 100 + alarm.getMm(),
                intent,
                0
        );

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarm.getHh());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarm.getMm());

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() >= calendar.getTimeInMillis()) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
        }

        if(alarm.getRepeat().equals(context.getString(R.string.text_onetime))) {
            manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, ///ONETIME
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    pendingIntent
            );
        } else if(alarm.getRepeat().equals(context.getString(R.string.text_daily))) {
            manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, ///DAILY
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                    pendingIntent
            );
        } else if(alarm.getRepeat().equals(context.getString(R.string.text_weekly))) {
            manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, ///WEEKLY
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7,
                    pendingIntent
            );
        }

        if(flag == WITH_DATABASE) {
            AlarmDBHelper dbHelper = new AlarmDBHelper(context);
            SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(AlarmContract.AlarmsEntry.COLUMN_ENABLED, AlarmContract.ENABLED);
            String selection = AlarmContract.AlarmsEntry._ID + " LIKE ?";
            String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(alarm.getId()) };

            database.update(
                    AlarmContract.AlarmsEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    values,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs
            );

            database.close();
            dbHelper.close();
        }
    }

    public static void updateAlarm(Context context, Alarm alarm) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("hh", alarm.getHh());
        bundle.putInt("mm", alarm.getMm());
        bundle.putInt("id", alarm.getId());
        bundle.putString("rpt", alarm.getRepeat());
        bundle.putString("state", alarm.getState());
        bundle.putString("text", alarm.getText());

        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent;

        int solution = 45-12;
        int userSolution = 36;
        if(solution!=userSolution) {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    context,
                    alarm.getHh() * 100 + alarm.getMm(),
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
            manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        }
        else
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    context,
                    alarm.getHh() * 100 + alarm.getMm(),
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE
            );

       /* PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                alarm.getHh() * 100 + alarm.getMm(),
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
*/
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarm.getHh());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarm.getMm());
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);

        if(alarm.getRepeat().equals(context.getString(R.string.text_onetime))) {
            manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, ///ONETIME
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    pendingIntent
            );
        } else if(alarm.getRepeat().equals(context.getString(R.string.text_daily))) {
            manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, ///DAILY
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                    pendingIntent
            );
        } else if(alarm.getRepeat().equals(context.getString(R.string.text_weekly))) {
            manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, ///WEEKLY
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7,
                    pendingIntent
            );
        }

    }

    public static void cancelAlarm(Context context, Alarm alarm) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class); ///!!!!!!!

        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;

        int solution = 45-12;
        int userSolution = 36;
        if(solution!=userSolution) {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    context,
                    alarm.getHh() * 100 + alarm.getMm(),
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            );
            manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        }
        else
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    context,
                    alarm.getHh() * 100 + alarm.getMm(),
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE
            );

        AlarmDBHelper dbHelper = new AlarmDBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(AlarmContract.AlarmsEntry.COLUMN_ENABLED, AlarmContract.DISABLED);
        String selection = AlarmContract.AlarmsEntry._ID + " LIKE ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(alarm.getId()) };

        database.update(
                AlarmContract.AlarmsEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                values,
                selection,
                selectionArgs
        );

        database.close();
        dbHelper.close();
    }

}
```

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Какие варианты пробовали? какие ошибки?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид для начала я пробовал условие `int solution = 45-12;
        int userSolution = 36;
        if(solution==userSolution)
            manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        else {
            return;
        }` я задавал неверное условие, для проверки, будет ли какая-то реакция. Но будильник благополучно выключался и при условии. После чего я немного менял данное условие,но ничего не помогало. Потом пробовал это реализовать с помощью AlertDialog, которое должно появляться вместе с запуском будильника и исчезать после ввода верного ответа, но я не работал ранее с AlertDialog.